# how to initialize the struct of following structure in golang

Tags: json, go, struct

I have the following data structure. I need to initialize it without using nested initialization. This data structure will be flushed to output a json file later.

```
type GeneratePlan struct{
    Mode    string `json:"mode"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Schema  string `json:"schema"`
    Version string `json:"version"`
    Attack_plans []struct1 `json:"attack-plans"`

} 

type struct1 struct {
    Attack_plan Attack_plan `json:"attack-plan"`
}


type Attack_plan struct{
    Attack_resouces []struct2 `json:"attack-resources"`
}

type struct2 struct {
    Attack_resource Attack_resource `json:"attack-resource"`
}
```

Problem is when I try to append the variable of type struct2 to the Attack_resources[] slice, it gives the error as

```
cannot use struct2 (type *structs.Struct2) as type structs.Struct2 in append
```

How can we initialize the struct without using new or any ptr? As, if we use any of the standard struct initialization technique, it will give the above error.
If I change the above data structure and make it hold a pointer to another struct, it doesn't store the values correctly. I am very new to golang. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make sure to post the actual failing code in the future. The error message also does not match your code sample.

Your problem is that you are appending a pointer value to a slice of structs. Either change the slice definition to be a `[]*Struct2`, or dereference the pointer as in `x.Attack_resources = append(x.Attack_resources, *struct2)`.

Note that snake_case is generally not encouraged  in go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize a struct value using:

```
resource := struct2{}
```

As @nothingmuch pointed out, if you have a struct pointer and need the underlying value, you can dereference the pointer using:

```
deref := *resource
```